# Javascript regex pattern match multiple strings ( AND, OR, NEAR/n, P/n )

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to filter a collection of strings based on a rather complex query 
I have query input as a string

```
var query1 ='Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* ) AND BLOOD near/10 (Point P/1 Care)';
```

From this query INPUT string I want to collect just the important words:

```
var words= 'Abbott assay* test* BLOOD Point care';
```

The query can change for example:

```
var query2='(assay* OR test* OR analy* OR array) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care)';
```

from this query need to collect

```
var words='assay* test* analy* array Abbott Point Care';
```

I'm looking for your suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use `|` in your regex to capture the words and/or special characters that you want to remove:

```
([()]|AND|OR|(NEAR|P)\/\d+) ?
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/rqpmXr/2

Note the `/gi` in the regex options, with `i` meaning that it's case insensitive.

**EXPLANATION:**

- `([()]|AND|OR|(NEAR|P)\/\d+)` - This is a capture group containing all the words you specified in your title, plus the parentheses.
- `(NEAR|P)\/\d+` - Just to clear out this part, `\d+` means that one or more digits are following the words `NEAR` or `P`.
- `?` - This captures the possible trailing space after the captured word.

Comment: there is only one issue here if "(assay* OR test*) AND BLOOD" it will give me "assay* test*BLOOD" and that's wrong need all the words separate

Comment: You can modify the regex to account for the spaces on both cases (parentheses and word): `?[()]|(AND|OR|(NEAR|P)\/\d+) ?`. [Click for demo](https://regex101.com/r/rqpmXr/3).